# Applying a function over a dataframe won't work, AttributeError error in function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to apply a function which will return 'cleaned' email values. However, I'm having difficulty applying my function over my respected column.

Please recommend best approach.

**Sample data:**

```
sample_data= {'email': ['Sam@mail.com','Sam@mail.com',
                        'Doug@mail.com', 'Doug@mail.com',
                       np.NAN, np.NAN],
              'price': [25.95, 31.25, 34.95, 19.95, 59.95, 15.75]}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)

# print(sample_df)
    email   price
0   Sam@mail.com    25.95
1   Sam@mail.com    31.25
2   Doug@mail.com   34.95
3   Doug@mail.com   19.95
4   NaN     59.95
5   NaN     15.75
```

**Apply function:**

```
def clean_emails(s):
    emails = {x: str(x).lower() for x in s.unique()}
    return s.map(emails)

# Passing the column directly into the function works
sample_df.email = clean_emails(sample_df.email)

# So does passing the entire df into an apply statement
sample_df = sample_df.apply(clean_emails)

print(sample_df)

    email   price
0   sam@mail.com    25.95
1   sam@mail.com    31.25
2   doug@mail.com   34.95
3   doug@mail.com   19.95
4   nan     59.95
5   nan     15.75
```

As demonstrated, passing the column directly into the function works. So does applying the entire df. My concern is for larger datasets, passing a single column to the function.

***To summarize,*** is passing a single column of a df into a function the best approach for solving this? Or can `apply` be used?

Comment: for full dataframe you should use `applymap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you have is using `unique()` which is not a property of a DataFrame. It seems you meant to apply it to the Series, not the DataFrame.

A couple of things to keep in mind.

1. Your function will apply `str` to `NaN` values and turn them into strings which then won't be recognized by `pd.isnull`. I don't think you want that
2. I forgot :)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample_data= pd.DataFrame({'email': ['Sam@mail.com','Sam@mail.com', 'Doug@mail.com', 'Doug@mail.com', np.NAN, np.NAN],
'price': [25.95, 31.25, 34.95, 19.95, 59.95, 15.75]})

sample_data.email =  sample_data.email.str.lower()
```

You could also just do this

```
email_dict = {el: el.lower() for el in sample_data.email.unique() if pd.notnull(el)}
sample_data.email = sample_data.email.replace(email_dict)
```

Comment: In a larger `df`, this will get really slow.

Comment: @YaakovBressler Why? Is it because it creates a new series object?

Comment: Each row is converted into a string. With mapping through a dict, repeats are sped up.

Comment: @YaakovBressler Right. I was assuming the data wasn't large and I was hoping to show that Pandas have built in properties to access string representations of the (non null) elements. I think the `replace` property is faster and I think that's what the OP wanted to use. I edited my answer